# Problem on data feeding to a private confluent cloud kafka on Azure

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, confluent-cloud, private-cluster

I've setup a private Confluent cloud cluster on Azure according to the official doc (https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/networking/private-links/azure-privatelink.html)

I want to use Azure firewall DNAT the port 9092 to the kafka bootstrap server for data feeding. But there is a connection error, address unreachable. Somehow, the address as shown in the error is an internal address (which is not routable).

Came across a similar doc in confluent cloud (https://forum.confluent.io/t/kafka-does-not-works-through-nat-as-expected/4351/2). Where and how can I setup the listener on Confluent cloud? The cli "kubectl confluent cluster kafka listeners" seems is not working on confluent cloud, and I cannot find any configuration files that I can include this settings as well.

Comment: `kubectl confluent ...` is for CFK Operator, not Confuent Cloud CLI. For that, use `ccloud` command

Comment: thank you. do you mean the confluent cli as in this ref: https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/command-reference/overview.html

is it even possible to change listener conf on confluent cloud?

Comment: I do not believe you can modify listeners of the hosted Confluent Cloud service, no. If that's what you want, then you'll need to install CFK on AKS or run Confluent Platform on Azure Compute on your own. Beyond that, I suggest contacting Confluent Support if their documentation isn't helping you